# how to print certain text in a line

Tags: awk

How can I get the result in the below format?

Below is the line on which action needs to be performed.
Empty Results found in `BusListingAction/buslisting.htm` for:

```
DepartureCity: BARMER  ArrivalCity BIKANER   DepartureDate 03/02/2015 cSessionID: 14229435030636234
```

I need the below output using awk command:

```
BARMER BIKANER DepartureDate-03/02/2015
```

Comment: Your formatting is unclear. Please check that the input line is like I made it. It's not important for `awk` but strange that only some of the category fields have a trailing colon.

Answer (score 2):

That is very basic usage of `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $2,$4,$5"-"$6}' file
BARMER BIKANER DepartureDate-03/02/2015
```